# jQuery explode effect is not working

Tags: jquery

I am using below code, but nothing is happening...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn4").click(function(){
        $(".shake").show("explode", { pieces: 16 }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```css
.shake {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    background: #666; 
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn4">Shake</button>
<div class="shake"></div>
```

Comment: `"explode"` is not a valid argument to `show()` in jQuery Core. Did you include jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, Jquery UI is included..

Comment: You should use .toggle instead of .show

Comment: Thanks friends, its working fine when I am using toggle.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
$( ".shake" ).toggle( "explode" );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you included the libraries. your code should be like this.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>explode demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div><input type"button" id="toggle"></div>

<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "explode" );
});
</script>

</body>
```

for your code i included the answer below

[your code answer](http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1569/)